# VisualStudio 2010 C# - checkboxes in ListGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, checkbox, datagridview

So, I have a `DataGridView` with couple of columns. The first one (index=0) contains one checkbox per row.
**When application is running :** I set checkbox true for some of rows, and when I trigger the event application ignores checkbox that I clicked last. But when I click on CheckAll button that I made the action works for every item.

```
 private void  nameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < datagridview1.RowCount; i++)
    {
       try
       {
         if ((bool)datagridview1[0, i].Value){           
           // do something with row values
         }
       }
       catch (Exception ex) {
         // this is because if checkbox is not checked
         // the compiler throws NullReferenceException
       }
    }
}
```

Even stranger is that I have written code with same `for(){}` elsewhere in project and that code works with no anomaly like that. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for reading this.

Comment: u mean out of 10 record if you select 1,2 and 3 it returns you the 1 and 2 only as selected records?? is it so??

Comment: yes, it is like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally. Visual Studio did not count the last row checked because the editing for that cell was not finished.
I solved problem with this line of code.

datagridview1.EndEdit();

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create the loop with a foreach instead, that will insure that each row is checked.  Possibly, you could use i < datagridview1.Rows.Count instead, if you need to keep it as a for loop.
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in datagridview1.Rows)
{
    loop contents here....
}

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip, I'll try and let you know if that is helpful :)

Comment: Sorry for slow answer guys, I've been unable to connect to internet..foreach won't work because of the: **Error 1** foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' because 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I use .NET 3.5 btw, maybe this information will help someone to figure out what is happening.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't read this closely enough to notice WinForms vs WebForms...have you tried  i <= kontakti.RowCount; as well?

Comment: Tried with <= same result, thanks for trying to help